# Object manipulation javascript, add value of object to an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, javascript-objects

An example will speak for itself :

Array of Object :

```
[{ 
    userId: 'ab4e3870-287e-11e7-b5a1-abb6183e9866',
    email: 'email1@hotmail.com' 
},{ 
    userId: 'ae149220-2883-11e7-bbf9-1fb134f2b4ad',
    email: 'email2@hotmail.com' 
}]
```

Object

```
{ 
    'ab4e3870-287e-11e7-b5a1-abb6183e9866': { name: 'john', roles: 'detective'},
    'ae149220-2883-11e7-bbf9-1fb134f2b4ad': { name: 'james', roles: 'plumber'}, 
}
```

The result i'd like would be :

```
[{ 
    userId: 'ab4e3870-287e-11e7-b5a1-abb6183e9866',
    email: 'email1@hotmail.com',
    name: 'john', 
    roles: 'detective' 
},{ 
    userId: 'ae149220-2883-11e7-bbf9-1fb134f2b4ad',
    email: 'email2@hotmail.com',
    name: 'james', 
    roles: 'plumber' 
}]
```

So basically, the value of the key that match the userId in Object is added to that object in the array.

Is there some simple way I don't see to do that? Without external libraries in ES6?

Comment: Of course, just iterate through the array and the object keys and check whether the array object has a userId equal to the other object's key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [{ 
    userId: 'ab4e3870-287e-11e7-b5a1-abb6183e9866',
    email: 'email1@hotmail.com' 
},{ 
    userId: 'ae149220-2883-11e7-bbf9-1fb134f2b4ad',
    email: 'email2@hotmail.com' 
}]

var d = { 
    'ab4e3870-287e-11e7-b5a1-abb6183e9866': { name: 'john', roles: 'detective'},
    'ae149220-2883-11e7-bbf9-1fb134f2b4ad': { name: 'james', roles: 'plumber'}, 
};
```

## Using ES6 spread operator `...`

```
data = data.map(function(item) {
  return {...item, ...d[item.userId]}
});
```

## ES5: By adding properties manually

```
data = data.map(function(item) {
  item.name = d[item.userId].name;
  item.roles = d[item.userId].roles;
  return item;
});
```